# What does <variable> means?

Tags: android, variables, android-arrayadapter

I was looking for some codes to make a Spinner then I noticed that they use an ArrayAdapter like this:

`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );`

My question is, what does the <> do? I investigate a bit and its not a cast (I think) adn i havent found something yet.

Comment: Look into [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;` means [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) is of the type `CharSequence`. You can have adapter of any kind, say, for example, `ArrayAdapter<String>`, here ArrayAdapter is of type String.

You can define your custom `ArrayAdapter` too, by creating a class that extends ArrayAdapter and override its methods as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know c and c++ we used arrays of data type char to store a stirng 
Same way when you want to store array or string you create something like this

```
      String[] myArray = {"abc", "def", "ghi"} ;
```

Overloading in java helps is using same function defined in a class with different parameters to do different set of instructions which are changed as per the arguments as received via calls.

Same way when ArrayAdapter is called the dataType  defines the type of array Adapter 
As you might want to think it as

```
       String ArrayAdapter variableName = new String ArrayAdapter () ;
```

But as u can notice we are trying to define two things i.e.  The variable is a string but the variable is also an ArrayAdapter, this creates mess for java jdk developers to change the rules of compiling java files. 
So they tried to make something like

```
           ArrayAdapter<String> variableName = new ArrayAdapter<String>  () ;
```

Hope i helped..